# How can I output this in a handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using express and handlebars, and I have the following express code in the controller for a handlebars template.

```js
     getUserID = function (request, response ) {
        var userIDtest = registerRepository.getUserID('PretendthisisauserID');
            return userIDtest;
        },
```

How can I output what is contained within "userIDtest"  to a

tag or something in a handlebars template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response.locals.userIDtest = userIDtest;
```

And the access it like this:

```
{{userIDtest}}
```